# Can't extract file with non-ascii name from zip archive

Tags: zip, encoding, archiving

I am using Linux Slackware 14, downloaded a zip archive with a file, containing Russian characters in it's name. Now when I try to unzip it in console, it prints an error and doesn't unzip:

```
bash-4.2$ unzip ./mmk.zip 
Archive:  ./mmk.zip
error:  cannot create _??????? ?.?., ???????? ??????????? ?????.djvu
        Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
```

I suspect, that they used CP-1251 encoding in file name instead of utf-8. How to fix?

Comment: Not sure, but [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621330/how-can-i-avoid-broken-languages-when-unzipping-unicode-files) may solve your problem.  (I know this is really old, but maybe for folks who run into this question in the future.)